# Вызов функции из родительского компонента React, без редакс

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу дипломный проект. Проект представляет из себя SPA с использованием Rest API
(все пишу сам и впервые). Выглядеть это будет как интерактивные курсы. У меня есть индексный файл, в котором есть запрос к серверу, который получает все возможные данные (Название курса, темы курса, текст лекций, вопросы к теме и ответы на них)

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Admin from './components/Admin'

let header = new Headers({
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Accept': 'application/json'
}) 

let myInit = { method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    header: header,
 }
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/start';

ReactDOM.render(<div id="preloader">
     <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));

(function () {
 fetch(endpoint, myInit)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then()
  .then((res) => {
   console.log(res)
   ReactDOM.render(<Admin data={res} />, document.getElementById('root'));
   
  })
})()
```

Ресурс имеем также кабинет администратора с панелью управления данными (удалить, просмотреть, добавить)
Проблема заключается в том что приложение получает данные сразу при загрузке, но если предположим мы добавим какой либо новый курс, то запроса к серверу не происходит и данные не рендерятся снова, потому новый курс не отобразится до момента перезагрузки страницы. Повторюсь, я пишу впервые и потому не могу грамотно разработать взаимосвязь между компонентами, а сроки поджимают.

**Можно ли решить эту проблему, вызывая функцию из индексного файла каждый раз при добавлении новой информации?**

Comment: В компонент `Admin` в `componentDidMount` создайте интервал, который каждые несколько секунд будет брать данные с сервера. Также у компонента `Admin` нужно создать состояние `res`, в которое и будут записываться все данные с сервера через `this.setState()`. Этот `res` и рендерьте в `Admin` там, где и рендерили, но теперь уже через `this.state.res`.

Comment: Могу ли я сделать это же, но в индексном файле, так как именно в нем идет запрос?

Comment: Да, оберните `fetch` в `setInterval`. Не знаю, как реакт к этому отнесется, но работать должно. Учтите, что так делать не стоит в серьезных проектах.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Конечно возможно не лучшее решение для продакшена, но для меня просто сокровище. Искренне благодарен и доволен как слон.